# e.which: Non numeric comparison

Tags: jquery, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a legacy jquery method which starts like this:

```
$(function() {
    $(document).keypress(function(e) {
        if ($(document.activeElement).is('body')) {
            if (e.which==48) { // 0
```

I want to clean up the code, to make it more readable.

How can I check if the user has pressed the key '0'?

Are there constants, or can you use `if (e.which==unkown_method('0')) { ...`

Hint: Code works, but want it to be without magic numbers.

**Solution**

with the help of user "Archer" I use this solution now:

```
        var key=String.fromCharCode(e.which);

        if (key=="0") {
            ...
        }
        else if (key=="5") {
            ...
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're asking what I think you're asking then this should help...

```
if (String.fromCharCode(e.which) == "0") { etc..
```

**Edit** This next bit is not actually relevant any more since jQuery standardises the event so it always uses `which`, but I'll leave it here for reference.

---

Also, bear in mind that different browsers have slightly different event types, so you may need to include this..

```
var key = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
if (key == "0") { etc..
```

That's a generic bit of code I've had lying round forever and, to be honest, I can't remember which browsers do what, but some use `keyCode` and some use `which`.  That covers both eventualities.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I guess e.which should work, since I use jquery. AFAIK I don't need to worry about different browsers in this case.

Comment: Yes, jQuery does standardize the event, so you can safely ignore the 2nd part of the answer (after a bit of googling).

Comment: With JQuery, you don't need to worry about broswer differences. Also, you might want to use `if(String.fromCharCode( e.which ).toLowerCase())` to grab only lower case codes. else your users will notice weird behaviour with caps lock & shift

Comment: @GaurishSharma Of course, if he's looking to trap keypresses on other characters that could become relevant, but I won't add it to the answer as it's not relevant to this particular question.

Comment: @Archer thank you for your help. I updated the answer, it contains my solution now.

Answer (score 0):

This plugin seems quite promising:

https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys

Is it any help?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){    
    $(document).keydown(function(e) {

  if ($(document.activeElement).is('body')) 
      {
         if (e.which==48) { 
           // do something..
         }
      }
     });
});
```

Use keydown event instead of keypress event. I hope so it will working properly.

Comment: Thank you, but that's not an answer to my question. I am looking for a betters solution for ``e.which==48`. The event stuff is working.